# Tkinter .set and .get not working in a window inside a window

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

```
from tkinter import *

def fun():
    trywindow=Tk()
    s=StringVar()
    entry=Entry(trywindow, textvariable=s)
    s.set("print")
    entry.pack()
    trywindow.mainloop()

root=Tk()
fun()

root.mainloop()
```

According to me after executing this code 2nd window should show enter block with text written in it "PRINTED" but it is blank.

Comment: Multiple instances of `Tk()` *simply do not work right*.  Use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows.

Comment: @jasonharper it's not so much that they don't work _right_, but rather they don't work the way you expect if you don't fulkly understand what an instance of `Tk` actually is.

Comment: Why do you think that calling `.get()` isn't working? Nowhere in your code do you call it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, using multiple instances of `Tk()` is discouraged. It leads to behavior that people don't expect, of which this question is a great example.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045508/3714930), all instances of `Tk` are completely isolated. Objects "belonging" to one of them can not be seen or used in the others.
What happens in your code is that you have two `Tk` instances: `root` and `trywindow`. Then you create a `StringVar`, without any arguments. This is the usual way to do this, but you actually can supply a master widget during construction. This way, you can control to which `Tk` instance your `StringVar` "belongs". See this quote from [effbot](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112025221/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm):

> The constructor argument is only relevant if you’re running Tkinter with multiple Tk instances (which you shouldn’t do, unless you really know what you’re doing).

If you don't specify the master, a master is chosen implicitly. I do believe it is always the first created instance of `Tk`. In your case, the `StringVar` is created with `root` as its master. Because these `Tk` instances are completely separated, `trywindow` and all widgets in it can not "see" the `StringVar` or any value in it.

So you could fix your code by simply passing `trywindow` to the `SringVar` constructuion:

```
s=StringVar(trywindow)
```

However, it's probably easier to change `trywindow` from a `Tk` instance to a `Toplevel` widget. This also creates a new window, but it belongs to the same `Tk` instance so you don't have these difficulties with separate `Tk` instances:

```
from tkinter import *

def fun():
    trywindow = Toplevel()
    s = StringVar()
    entry = Entry(trywindow, textvariable=s)
    s.set("print")
    entry.pack()
    trywindow.mainloop()

root = Tk()
fun()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Thank you for the explanation