# I am getting blank values from get method

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I integrate this code to my project file I get blank values from the get method but when I run this function in a single individual scratch file I get the values. IT shows no errors.

```
button6 = Button(configwin, text="IP ADDRESS", font=('arial', 15, 'bold'), fg="black", relief=RAISED,command=lambda:ipconfig())
button6.grid(row=0, column=0)


def ipconfig():
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("500x660")
    window.configure(bg="white")
    window.title("Ip configuration")

    u_ip = StringVar()
    u_sub = StringVar()
    Ipvalue = StringVar()

    lbl1 = Label(window, text="IP Address", bg="white", fg="navy blue", bd=10, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'))
    lbl1.grid(row=1, column=0)

    lbl2 = Label(window, text="Subnet Mask", bg="white", fg="navy blue", font=('arial', 10, 'bold'))
    lbl2.grid(row=2, column=0)

    lbl3 = Label(window, text="Interface", bg="white", fg="navy blue", font=('arial', 10, 'bold'))
    lbl3.grid(row=3, column=0)

    txt1 = Entry(window, fg="navy blue", font=('arial', 10), justify=LEFT, textvariable=Ipvalue)
    txt1.grid(row=1, column=1)

    txt2 = Entry(window, fg="navy blue", font=('arial', 10), justify=LEFT, textvariable=u_sub)
    txt2.grid(row=2, column=1)

    txt3 = Entry(window, fg="navy blue", font=('arial', 10), justify=LEFT, textvariable=u_ip)
    txt3.grid(row=3, column=1)

    button1 = Button(window, text="Submit", font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), fg="navy blue", command=lambda: Telnet1())
    button1.grid(row=10, column=1)

    def Telnet1():

        try:
            username = "fenil"
            password = "123456"
            port = 23
            cout = 20
            rout = 20
            print("o")
            print(u_ip)
            print(Ipvalue)
            print(u_sub)

            ip_address = Ipvalue.get()
            z = ip_address
            us_ip = u_ip.get()
            us_sub = u_sub.get()

            print(us_ip)
            print(z)
            print(us_sub)

            b = "192.168.0.109"
            # c = input("")
            d = telnetlib.Telnet(b, port, cout)
            print("Ok")
            # e=d.read_until("username",rout)
            d.write(username.encode("ascii") + b"\n")
            # f=d.read_until("password",rout)
            print("Ok1")
            d.write(password.encode("ascii") + b"\n")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Ok2")
            d.write(b"terminal length 0\n")
            time.sleep(1)
            d.write(b"\n")
            d.write(b"configure terminal")
            d.write(b"\n")
            time.sleep(1)
            d.write(b"int " + us_ip.encode("ascii") + b"\n")
            time.sleep(1)
            d.write(b"ip address " + z.encode("ascii") + b" " + us_sub.encode("ascii") + b"\n")
            time.sleep(1)
            d.write(b"no shut")
            d.write(b"\n")
            time.sleep(1)
            d.write(b"exit")
            d.write(b"\n")
            time.sleep(1)
            d.write(b"sh ip int br")

           g = d.read_very_eager()
            print(g)
            d.close()

        except IOError:
            print("error")

    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are both `configwin` and `window` instances of `Tk()`?  If so, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55217251/3714930).

Comment: Yes they both are.

Comment: So have you read the answer I linked?

Comment: @fenilshukla try passing the value of the _.get()_ method to the _Telnet1_ function